# What determines debugger run-time performance

Tags: python, performance, debugging, python-3.x

I have tried debugging Python 3 with Wing IDE (v.4.1.3) and Komodo IDE (v.7.0.0). As, expected the debugger adds a lot of run-time overhead. But what surprised me is how different the debuggers can be between each other.

Here are the run-times for the same program. No breakpoints or anything else, just a regular run without any actual debugging:

- executed by python interpreter: 26 sec
- executed by debugger #1: 137 sec
- executed by debugger #2: 1143 sec

I refer to the debuggers as anonymous #1 and #2 lest this becomes an unintentional (and possibly misguided) advertising for one of them.

Is one of the debuggers really 8 times "faster"?

Or is there some design trade-off, where a faster debugger gives up some features, or precision, or robustness, or whatever, in return for greater speed? If so, I'd love to know those details, whether for Wing/Komodo specifically, or Python debuggers in general.

Comment: Maybe it's waiting at a breakpoint?

Comment: @yak No breakpoints. Just straight run to the end.

Comment: There isn't many features there could be. I'd guess one is simply just 8 times as slow. But probably you'd have to analyze and profile the code to know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Doing an optimized Python debugger is as any other software: things can be really different performance-wise (I'm the PyDev author and I've done the PyDev debugger, so, I can comment on it, but not on the others, so, I'll just explain a bit on optimizing a Python debugger -- as I've spent a lot of time optimizing the PyDev debugger -- I won't really talk about other implementations as I don't know how they were done -- except for pdb, but pdb is not really a fast debugger implementation after it hits a breakpoint and you're stepping through it, although it does work well by running things untraced until you actually execute the code that'll start tracing your code).

Particularly, any 'naive' debugger can make your program much slower just by enabling the Python trace in each frame and checking if there's a breakpoint match for each line executed (this is roughly how pdb works: whenever you enter a context it'll trace it and for each line called it'll check if a breakpoint matches it, so, I believe any implementation that expects to be fast can't really rely on it).

I know the PyDev debugger has several optimizations... the major one is the following: when the debugger enters a new frame (i.e.: function) it will check if there's any 'potential' breakpoint that may be hit there and if there's not, it won't even trace that function (on the other hand, when a breakpoint is added later on after the program is executing, it'll have to go and reevaluate all previous assumptions, as any current frame could end up skipping a breakpoint). And if it determines that some frame should be traced, it'll create a new instance for that frame which will be responsible for caching all that's related to that frame (this was only really possible from Python 2.5, so, when working on Python 2.4 and earlier, unless the threadframe extension is installed, the debugger will try to emulate that, which will make it considerably slower on Python 2.4).

Also, the PyDev debugger currently takes advantage of Cython, even though this is only restricted to CPython... Jython, IronPython and PyPy don't take advantage of it), so, many optimizations are still done considering pure Python mode (thankfully Cython is close enough to Python so that few changes are needed in order to make it work faster on CPython with Cython).

Some related posts regarding PyDev debugger optimization evolution:

http://pydev.blogspot.co.id/2017/03/pydev-560-released-faster-debugger.html

http://pydev.blogspot.co.id/2016/01/pydev-451-debug-faster.html

http://pydev.blogspot.com/2008/02/pydev-debugger-and-psyco-speedups.html

http://pydev.blogspot.com/2005/10/high-speed-debugger.html

Anyways, running with the debugger in place will always add some overhead (even when heavily optimized such as the PyDev debugger), so, PyDev also provides the same approach that may be used in pdb: add a breakpoint in code and it'll only start tracing at that point (which is the remote debugger feature of PyDev): http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

And depending on the features you want the debugger to support, it can also be slower (e.g.: when you enable the break for caught exceptions in PyDev, the program will execute slower because it'll need to trace more things in order to properly break).

Comment: This is a perfect answer - sometimes I wait ages (even 3-4 orders of magnitude) for my code to reach a particular breakpoint and load its data from disk (I almost always test smaller sets while using debugger), but here I found a solution - just put a breakpoint in a function, not at the top level of the script and voila! Now it is really fast. Thanks really for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is like asking why is program A faster than program B. The reason may not be specific to the domain of debugging.

I would imagine most graphical debuggers are built on top or a frontend to the [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html) module provided in the python standard library (though not all are). The performance differences would mostly boil down to implementation details and GUI updating overhead. The difference could be as simple as doing unnecessary deep copies vs direct referencing in some layer of the code.

If you are concerned about debugger performance, then you should stick with the faster graphical debugger, unless it is not satisfying some feature you need. You are asking for feature differences; since this is the case, they are both obviously current serving your needs feature-wise.

If one debugger is losing precision or sacrificing robustness, then I would discount it immediately from consideration. I would chance a guess that the slower one is either:

- Doing extra work or unnecessary checks (if the developer doesn't trust other parts of the code, or their are too many layers or redundancy architecturally).
- Using some cache-unfriendly or wasteful representation or hasn't tuned or optimised the code algorithmically as much as the faster debugger. Correct data structure choice and algorithmic optimisations can make orders of magnitudes of difference. Using low-level optimisations (like ctypes, psyco, pyrex) etc.. you can make another order of magnitude of a difference. Remember python gives you flexible and powerful default containers that you always "pay" for, even if you dont need all their functionality.

I have found that [WinPDB](http://winpdb.org) is fairly lightweight, and is the one I usually use, since it doesnt tie me to an IDE, and supports remote debugging quite effectively. You might also want to try eclipse with [pydev](http://pydev.org/). Another new one I have just started playing around with is [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) which looks very promising. There is also a [list of python debuggers](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggers) on the python wiki. It might be worth giving the others a try.

As to why one is faster than the other, there are a multitude of possible factors. If you have access to the source of the debugger, you might be able to profile the debugger itself to identify the performance bottlenecks. But if you just want a fast debugger that handles all the basic use cases, just try a few more out, and stick with the fastest that serves your needs.

Comment: This is good explanation, thank you. Now I'm curious - what causes the 6x runtime overhead in even the faster debugger? After all, I don't have any breakpoints. All the debugger would need to do is catch the exception if any, and be able to tell me the values of all variables at each layer of the call stack. Isn't a tiny map from between physical and variable names sufficient?

Comment: @max No, depending on the implementation, you may have a lot of overhead, such as keeping and checking a model or representation of the state of the stack and current stack frames, when to break etc. If the  debugger code is built at a high abstraction level, there could be significant overhead as you get further "away from the metal". As you get "closer to the metal" with optimisations, e.g. using c extensions that make use of low-level operating system and hardware features, you lose the portability (i.e. it wont be pure python)

Comment: You may want to check out this book: [Gray Hat Python]  (http://www.amazon.com/Gray-Hat-Python-Programming-Engineers/dp/1593271921); specifically chapter 3, which is an excellent intro to the fundamentals of implementing debuggers in python